# SwiftUI Crash when scrolling a list

Tags: list, scroll, swiftui, tabview

Glad to post my first question here!

I've been playing around with SwiftUI for a few weeks now and during a bigger project, I found the following bug.

If you have a TabView and a list inside it, if you try to change the tab while the scroll animation takes place, the app will crash with **FATAL ERROR: "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT".**

**Console**:

- *BugTest[11830:362796] precondition failure: attribute failed to set an initial value: 98*

Have you ever encountered this? Is there any way I can solve this issue without changing my list into a ForEach?

Thank you in advance!

Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
                TabView {
                    list()
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "doc")
                                .font(.system(size: 25))
                    }

                    Text("Testing the bug")
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "list.dash")
                                .font(.system(size: 25))
                    }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct list: View {

    var body: some View {
        List(0..<50){_ in
            Text("test")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Xcode 11.2.1 (11B500) / iOS 13.2.2. Please try to wrap your list in `VStack` container, by my observations it is buggy to use dynamic-size views (like `List`, `ScrollView`) at top level of `body`

Comment: I embedded the list in a VStack but with no luck. I will stick to ForEach until this gets fixed. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Which Xcode/iOS versions do you use? Just to know. With such type of system level error it is good practice to note which environment is used. Thanks.

Comment: I am currently on 11.2.1 (11B500)

Comment: I will attach a video below so you can see the issue I am facing

Comment: here you can see it  we.tl/t-GM5K90xJjG

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error either. Using iPhone on iOS 13.3 and XCode Version 11.3 beta.

Comment: @SimonBachmann let me download the beta and I will come back with an update

Comment: @SimonBachmann I still encounter the issue even on 13.3. Please take a moment to watch this video we.tl/t-GM5K90xJjG

Comment: XCode 11.3.1 + iOS 13.3 the same

Comment: Cannot reproduce any more with Xcode 11.4 beta (11N111s) in Simulator and on iPhone 8 with iOS 13.4 beta (17E5223h)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This should work

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
            TabView {
               VStack{
                list()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "doc")
                            .font(.system(size: 25))
                }

                Text("Testing the bug")
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "list.dash")
                            .font(.system(size: 25))
                }
    }
}
}}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
}}

struct list: View {
var body: some View {
    List(0..<50){_ in
        Text("test")
    }
}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I slightly modified your version and it works in my case

Comment: Could you please explain the difference? Why that works? Looks like you simply removed his code to call list()

Comment: I see - you tried to put it in VStack. For me it doesn't help. Replacing with ForEach also doesn't help.

Comment: Don’t know but it weirdly works in my case. SwiftUI has lot of bugs with List. Could you try with Scroll View ? Or post the code where it doesn’t work for you.

Comment: I edited the code a bit but looks like could you please check? Looks like putting all tabs inside VStack is not what OP wanted. In this edition TabView won't show tabs at all I think.

Answer (score -2):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58574937/6594394), the error occurred because the items in the list were not conforming to the `Identifiable` protocol.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            list()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "doc")
                        .font(.system(size: 25))
            }

            Text("Testing the bug")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "list.dash")
                        .font(.system(size: 25))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct list: View {
    var elements: [CustomInt] = []

    init() {
        for i in 0...1000{
            elements.append(CustomInt(text:String(i)))
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        List(elements){element in
            Text(element.text)
        }
    }
}

struct CustomInt: Identifiable{
    var id = UUID()
    var text:String
}
```